# Changing collection in every iteration of ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have an ng-repeat that looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">
    <div ng-repeat="item in getItemsForDay(day)">
```

`getItemsForDay(day)` returns a `$firebaseArray` that is queried and filtered with the right data. Originally the `$firebaseArray` has a list of all the items for all the days. But I filter it down each time I call the method.

This results in

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop. 
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

How can I dynamically change the `$firebaseArray` so I can iterate through the correct data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) service. If the $firebaseArray has a specific property that you are trying to filter on you can do it simply with the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">
    <div ng-repeat="item in $firebaseArray | filter:{matchingProperty: day}:true"></div>
</div>
```

See this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/V28BWVOiZnMC0bvOwPpO) for a more in-depth example.

**JS**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  $scope.stuff = [{day: 1}, {day: 1}, {day: 2}, {day: 2}, {day: 3}, {day: 3}, {day: 4}, {day: 5}, {day: 6}, {day: 7}];
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">
      Day {{$index+1}} Matches:
      <div ng-repeat="s in stuff | filter:{day: day}:true">
        {{s.day}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

If you can't simply match on properties, then you can always build your own filter... here's a [good example](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) of how to do that.

Comment: Yes! Filtering the $firebaseArray worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad to help.